# Pandoc is missing a library file

Tags: libraries, shared-library

`pandoc-citeproc` is missing a library file:

```
[max@arch ~]$ pandoc-citeproc
pandoc-citeproc: error while loading shared libraries: libHStext-icu-0.7.0.1-qGJENUzIfHIw3gGVnpCOt-ghc8.2.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried reinstalling `pandoc-citeproc`, `haskell-text`, `haskell-text-icu`, `icu` and running `ldconfig`:

```
[max@arch ~]$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libHStext
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory
    libHStext-1.2.3.0-FxgEmn4RjqC37dwdnPGDhj-ghc8.2.2.so -> libHStext-1.2.3.0-FxgEmn4RjqC37dwdnPGDhj-ghc8.2.2.so
    libHStext-icu-0.7.0.1-BrRCvrI0J5D8igO871u2tp-ghc8.2.2.so -> libHStext-icu-0.7.0.1-BrRCvrI0J5D8igO871u2tp-ghc8.2.2.so
```

Don't know what to do here and I can't find anyone online with the same issue.

Comment: Would help you you post information about what distribution you are using...

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux, all packages are up to date.

Comment: edit you question please do not answer in the comment. Comments are here to help question but not answer. Plus, could you at least provide arch linux version.

Comment: @Kiwy Arch doesn't have versions; it's a rolling release, so "all packages are up to date" means that the system has the newest version of all applicable packages, even if it was freshly-installed from a five-year-old DVD

Comment: @Fox ho, didn't know that... Anyway that kind of information should be in the question not the comment ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was fixed in todays update...

Comment: what was the cause of this issue!? I'm having a similar issue now...